# Chained Imports in Python Producing Error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python and am working through its idiosyncrasies, and am having problems with something that should be simple.  I have main directory with main.py and some other files, and I have a subfolder holding classes for some specific processing.  So let's say my file structure looks like this:

```
root/main.py
root/more/foo.py
root/more/bar.py
```

File foo looks like this:

```
from bar import bar

class Foo():
    def __init__():
        myBar = bar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    G = Foo()
    print(G.myBar)
```

Main.py looks like:

```
import more.foo as f
.
.
.
```

When this line is called, the interpreter has no problem finding foo, but the import line raises an error in foo.py:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'

When I run foo natively, it has no problem finding bar and functions effectively.  Can you help me what's going on here, and what I can do to circumvent this issue?

I'm running Python 3.7 in OSX using PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that when you say you run `foo` natively, you are in the folder `more`.

To solve your issue, you simply need to import all classes everywhere in relation to its position from the `root` directory, because the entry point is in `main.py`.

This should work if you import `bar` from `more.bar`:

```
from more.bar import bar
```